# how to manage the timezone which are not directly supported in java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, zoneddatetime, zoneid

we are getting the ZoneId object by passing the id string -> `ZoneId.of("US/Alaska")`

While getting the timezone ids from java after passing the location name, we get error that `"Exception in thread "main" java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: EST"`

We get this exception for multiple location like -> `EST, America/Argentina, America/Indiana, America/Kentucky, America/North_Dakota`

What is the best way to handle such cases? is it good idea to get the ZoneId object by passing location Id?

Comment: What did you want for EST? Australian or North American Eastern Standard Time? With or without respecting daylight saving time? For the others they seem to consist of more time zones each, possibly only in order to treat historic data correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify cities not countries (most of them are cities), for example which city of **Argentina**?

```
America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
America/Argentina/Catamarca
America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia
America/Argentina/...
```

<strike>A list of valid Java timezones can be found here (***refer to the comments for better reference***):


*https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/*</strike>

---

**UPDATE:**

In order to get all available zone ids:

```
Set<String> zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
System.out.println("Available Zone Ids: \n" + String.join("\n", zoneIds));
```

Comment: or `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`

Comment: @OleV.V. this is just an example. I improve my answer a bit. Tnx

Comment: The link given is quite old.  The list on Wikipedia is better maintained: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones